# Setting background color for header of Angular Material Card

Tags: css, angular-material2

[They are using it throughout the documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/card/overview) but I cannot find how to do add color to the header myself. [image: pale gray header screenshot]

I assume there is a way to get a full bleed colored header without having to remove the padding from the card. `mat-card-title-group` also stays inside of the cards padding.

```
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-title>Notes</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-content>
        ...
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Is there another component I should be looking at instead?

*ps: I found questions in regard to the original angular material for angular 1 but did not find anything for 2+.*

Comment: this is not a mat-card component, it's the layout used to build the tutorial page

Comment: Thanks @Tamani, it sure seems like it is prevalent and similar enough that it should be included in the card but I guess it's just an issue to take up with them on github.

Comment: This answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45872178/how-to-get-mat-card-header-background-fully-colored-in-angular-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rendered `mat-card-header` looks like:

```
<mat-card-header _ngcontent-c22="" class="mat-card-header">
   ...
</mat-card-header>
```

So you can target it **from its component** with:

```
.mat-card-header {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Or from its **parent component** with:

```
::ng-deep .mat-card-header {
  background-color: red;
}
```

*(You should avoid styling component from parents.)*

---

**Edit:**
As you say in the comments, if you want to remove the padding you can add:

```
.mat-card {
   padding: 0; 
}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with this is that the header stays inside of the padding of the card, not "full-bleed". I would have to adjust the padding on the top and sides to accommodate. Which I could do but it seemed excessive for something I thought might already be available in the components.

Comment: haha, thank you didn't have to do that, I know how to remove. I just didn't want to then add another div around the content to have the padding for everything but the header. The question was more to see if there was some feature that I was missing vs how to do it myself.

Comment: According to the *(small)* [mat-card API](https://material.angular.io/components/card/api) there is no feature to do that :/ You can still do a [custom theme](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)  but that will need more work than just overriding current theme :p